# Print out JSON in given format

Tags: php, json, format

I have a database of website stat which recorded a user view. I'd like to read and export into JSON. I can do it but I'd like to re-write them into a given format. What should I do?

Expected JSON code: //originated from http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

```
callback(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */
[
/* Sep 2005 */
[1127088000000,52.64],
[1127174400000,53.19],
[1127260800000,52.11],
[1127347200000,51.90],
[1127433600000,53.20],
[1127692800000,53.84],
[1127779200000,53.44],
[1127865600000,51.08],
[1127952000000,52.34],
[1128038400000,53.61],
...
]);
```

Here is my code:

```
$sql_viewer="select sum(vwr_id) as num,vwr_date from car_viewer where vwr_tid='$_tid' group by year(vwr_date) desc, month(vwr_date) desc";
$result_viewer=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_viewer);
while($rec_viewer=mysql_fetch_array($result_viewer)){
    $_viewerDate=$rec_viewer['vwr_date'];
    $_viewerNum=$rec_viewer['num'];
    foreach($rec_viewer as $key=>$val){
        $arr[$key]=$val;
    }
    $main_arr[]=$arr;
}
echo json_encode($main_arr);
```

Result JSON:

```
[{"0":"221944676","num":"221944676","1":"2012-09-01 00:20:08","vwr_date":"2012-09-01 00:20:08"},{"0":"66772926","num":"66772926","1":"2012-08-09 23:35:04","vwr_date":"2012-08-09 23:35:04"},{"0":"609","num":"609","1":"2012-02-20 22:40:29","vwr_date":"2012-02-20 22:40:29"}]
```

The question is how can I re-write the result JSON into the expected format above?
Regards,

Comment: well, at the very least you do need to remove the lines that add string keys to your array

Comment: Do you not need brackets around all those arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure but I really want to make the result similar to the given format from http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

Comment: @Wilf Do you not see the brackets around the data there? You also need to call the callback(), adding that to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the inner arrays had both numeric and integer indexes.

```
$sql_viewer="select sum(vwr_id) as num,vwr_date from car_viewer where vwr_tid='$_tid' group by year(vwr_date) desc, month(vwr_date) desc";
$result_viewer=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_viewer);
while($rec_viewer=mysql_fetch_array($result_viewer)){
    $_viewerDate=$rec_viewer['vwr_date'];
    $_viewerNum= intval ( $rec_viewer['num'] );
    // Create an array with just integer indexes
    $main_arr[]=array(strtotime($_viewerDate) * 1000, $_viewerNum);
}

echo 'callback(' . json_encode($main_arr) . ');';
```

, the code above makes the inner array have only integer indexes

Comment: Well, @Juan
Your code is near but how can I get rid of "" in the second array value?

    [[1346486142,"1927957"],[1343754810,"214726365"],[1341076182,"203617389"],[1338486790,"104360993"],[1335809973,"111783141"],[1333213548,"224419560"],[1330534843,"723663992"],[1328098973,"33952961"],[1327728151,"5050"]]`

Comment: @Wilf, it also looks like you need JS timestamps, so you need to multiply the the first value in array by 1000

Answer (score 1):

#### Update: updated answer without trailing comma and new line.

Just use your own `echo` instead of `json_encode`:

Replace:

```
echo json_encode($main_arr);
```

With:

```
$final = "";
foreach ($main_arr as $key => $value)
    $final .= "[$key, $value],\n";
echo substr($final, 0, -3);
```

Comment: The output the OP desires doesn't appear to really be "JSON", just a key-value pair listing.  As such, I think this is a reasonable solution.  If the output potentially has multiple "fields" (i.e. not just key-value pairs) then this approach might not work, but would need more clarity from the OP.

Comment: @JuanMendes The OP doesn't want a JSON!

Comment: Whoz it? @JuanMendes? Even after explaining it is not a JSON that the OP wants, then why the downvote?

Comment: @JuanMendes Okay, lemme be polite. Sorry for the rudeness. Well, the OP wanted a solution and I gave it. Can you please remove the downvote?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I will, if you fix your answer, right now you have a trailing comma, the arrays do not contain what the OP asked, and it won't work if there are any characters that need to be escaped. If there was a way to just remove the down vote, I would do  it.

Comment: By the way, the OP does want JSON, see the link on the question, the arrays are wrapped with `[]`, which makes it valid JSON, therefore, trying to print it on your own is a bad idea

Comment: Yup, done buddy! Hope it is fine now! :) What's the issue, in either case? JSON is totally different from what OP expects right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It isn't, each element in the array is an object, you can't just loop over the `$main_arr` and print out the result, each `$value` will not print what you may be thinking, plus it still won't work if any of the values contain quotes, or any other JS characters that need escaping

Comment: @Praveen, Your method is excellent but as the original link I just added. There's a special way of beginning and ending the code. No "," at the last line of JSON. How can I get rid of it and close with "]);"

Comment: @Wilf My method now doesn't have the ending `,`. Just `echo "([";` at the first and `echo "]);";` at the end na?

Comment: @Wilf That is a bad approach, what you need to create is JSON, you should use `json_encode`, as I showed you in my answer, then you don't have to worry about all the problems I mentioned

Comment: @Wilf What you needed is not a JSON I guess. It is a format. And I don't understand why I need to use `json_encode` as Juan says. But well, it works. :)

Comment: @Praveen, Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/spline/ so you can see the importance of format in JSON of the script. Otherwise it won't work. And I guess it a must :S

Comment: @Wilf, The only reason Praveen thought you didn't need JSON is because you didn't post the full data in your question, I fixed it. You do need JSON. Anyway I already told you this approach is very error prone, why are you insisting on this problematic approach when I posted something that is a lot closer to what you need?

Comment: @JuanMendes, Sorry to keep asking. I didn't see there's a new answer posted. Your answer is what I want but the chart still cannot display. I don't know why. The script format is exactly the same as the original... Gotta find out. Appreciate

Comment: @Wilf If the output of your script is correct, that means that the question itself has been answered and should be marked as such. You shouldn't wait until you resolve all the peripheral issues until you mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find out the problem - cannot display chart. Because I done mySQL wrong. So the result is not rendered correctly. Below is the working one. Thanks to @Juan Mendes. For any help.

```
$sql_vwr="select vwr_date from car_viewer where vwr_tid='$_tid' group by date(vwr_date) order by date(vwr_date) asc";
$result_vwr=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_vwr);
while($rec_vwr=mysql_fetch_array($result_vwr)){
    $_vwrDate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rec_vwr['vwr_date']));
    $_vwrDateTime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($rec_vwr['vwr_date']));

    //get num by date
    $sql_nVwr="select vwr_id from car_viewer where vwr_date like '$_vwrDate%' and vwr_tid='$_tid'";
    $result_nVwr=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_nVwr);
    $_nVwr=mysql_num_rows($result_nVwr);

    // Create an array with just integer indexes
    $main_arr[]=array(strtotime($_vwrDateTime) *1000, (int)$_nVwr);
}   
echo $_c .'(' . json_encode($main_arr) . ');';
```